# Run powershell script as local administrator in Jenkins

Tags: powershell, jenkins

I made a powershell script to run from jenkins on windows Server 8 R2
when i run this script as local administrator count in server it works perfectly but when i run it from jenkins it doesnt work

```
Exception lors de l'appel de Run avec 6 argument(s): Exception de HRESULT : 0x800A01A
```

Does anyone know what the problem is?
this is the code

```
$macroBook = "E:\cmd\FLV\flv.xlsm"
$procedureName = "ThisWorkbook.sendflvvbs"
$macroBookFullPath = (ls $macroBook).FullName
$macroProcName = (ls $macroBook).Name + "!" + $procedureName
$excelApp = New-Object -com "Excel.Application"
try {
    #$excelApp.DisplayAlerts = $false
    $excelApp.Workbooks.Open($macroBookFullPath)
    $excelApp.Application.Run($macroProcName, 'PROD', 'V-7-06-61-0', '141', '27/12/2016',  '')
}    
finally {
    $excelApp.DisplayAlerts = $false
    $excelApp.Quit()
}
```

Comment: Probably Excel.Application requires interactive mode.

Comment: Try to set "Allow service to interact with desktop" option https://lostechies.com/keithdahlby/2011/08/13/allowing-a-windows-service-to-interact-with-desktop-without-localsystem/